# R: ggmap: How do I draw lines using only known angles on a ggmap? My geom_spoke method is not working

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap, rgooglemaps

I am attempting to draw lines in polar coordinates on a `ggmap`. The general method works fine in `ggplot`:

```
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

#####################################


## build data frame with triangulation data

t1 <- c(534325, 4858925, 338, 0955)
t2 <- c(534383, 4859261, 290, 1010)
t3 <- c(534386, 4859011, 301, 1015)

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(t1, t2, t3))
colnames(df) <- c("Easting", "Northing", "Azimuth", "Time")
df$Time <- as.character(df$Time)

## plot coordinates with triangulation

ggplot(df, aes(x=Easting, y=Northing, label=Time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(nudge_x = 50) + 
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = Azimuth, radius = -500)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Triangulation with no base map:

[image: img1]

This is what I want, but with no base map in the background.

However, when I attempt this method in `ggmap`:

```
## convert utms to lat long

utmcoor <- SpatialPoints(cbind(df$Easting,df$Northing), 
proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12"))
lonlatcoor <- as.data.frame(spTransform(utmcoor,CRS("+proj=longlat")))
colnames(lonlatcoor) <- c("lon", "lat")

df$lon <- lonlatcoor$lon
df$lat <- lonlatcoor$lat

## plot on base map

zoom <- 15 

meanlon <- mean(df$lon)
meanlat <- mean(df$lat)

basemap <- get_googlemap(center=c(lon=meanlon, lat=meanlat), zoom=zoom, 
maptype="hybrid")

ggmap(basemap) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat), colour="red", size=2, data=df) +
  geom_spoke(aes(x=lon, y=lat, angle = Azimuth), data=df, radius=-200) + 
  theme_void()
```

I get the error

```
Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

The code works fine without the `geom_spoke` line, resulting in basemap without triangulations:

[image: img2]

I understand that this function is generally used for things like quiver plots. Does `ggmap` not support `geom_spoke`? Is there a better function altogether that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused. Where are there polar coordinates?

Comment: Well it's not a polar coordinate system, I just meant to say that the data with which I want to draw the lines is an Azimuth (i.e. angle) where 0 degrees is north.

Comment: And the azimuths are the third column in my df; they correspond to the angles of the lines drawn in the "triangulation with no base map" image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the coordinates: You're giving `geom_spoke` a radius of -200, but the coordinates you're working with are several orders of magnitude smaller. I took out the `theme_void` just to remind myself of how small the scale is; you want a radius of something like 0.01. Mess around with the radius value I put here.

`geom_spoke` basically does a little trigonometry behind the scenes to calculate the endpoint of each spoke, then draws a segment. If that endpoint is out of the bounds of the plot, you get that missing values warning. I'm not sure if -200 is the radius you're sticking with, or just a dummy value, but you could use your original coordinates and angles to calculate the endpoints, then project those points to figure out the radius. Or just use those endpoints to draw the `geom_segment` yourself. I'll leave those calculations to you, or it might make for another question. I'm pretty partial to `sf` and have a feeling that could provide an easy enough way to get those points.

```r
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

# .....
# everything up until ggmap is the same as in question

ggmap(basemap) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat), colour="red", size=2, data=df) +
  geom_spoke(aes(x=lon, y=lat, angle = Azimuth), data=df, radius = -1e-2)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Yes, this -200 was a dummy value. I did play around with it but did not go small enough. In the ggplot I had used -500, but since I converted from UTM's (in the ggplot) to lat long (in the ggmap) this relative magnitude of this dummy value changed as well. Silly me!